# What are the steps to take to get specific information from SNMP?

Tags: snmp, snmpwalk, fortigate

I want to query a FortiGate for its CPU usage.
Per Fortinet documentation, the variable to use is fgPerCpuHighDetails:

```
$ grep fgPerCpuHighDetails /home/qa/.snmp/mibs/FORTINET-*
/home/qa/.snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib:fgPerCpuHighDetails OBJECT-TYPE
/home/qa/.snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib:    OBJECTS     { fnSysSerial, sysName, fgPerCpuHighDetails }
/home/qa/.snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib:                fgProcModMemCapacity, fgProcModMemUsage, fgPerCpuHighDetails,
```

However, when I try to probe fgPerCpuHighDetails, I get:

```
$ snmpget -v2c -cpublic -mALL 192.168.1.99 fgPerCpuHighDetails
FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB::fgPerCpuHighDetails = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

Can you recommend any URL that explains the steps to take to get information from SNMP?

---

```
$ sudo systemctl status snmpd -l
● snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-07-17 16:46:31 PDT; 21h ago
 Main PID: 879 (snmpd)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/snmpd.service
           └─879 /usr/sbin/snmpd -LS0-6d -f

Jul 17 16:46:30 vestal8 systemd[1]: Starting Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon....
Jul 17 16:46:31 vestal8 snmpd[879]: NET-SNMP version 5.7.2
Jul 17 16:46:31 vestal8 systemd[1]: Started Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon..

$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.1.99 fgPerCpuHighDetails
fgPerCpuHighDetails: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> fgPerCpuHighDetails)
```

Comment: Is the `systemctl status` output from the FortiGate? Odd, I've never heard of it being Linux-based.

Comment: No, @grawity, the `systemctl status` is the output from the SNMP server, which is hosted on CentOS.

Comment: So is that SNMP server supposed to relay the queries to the FortiGate device that you mentioned? And if not, what's its purpose?

Comment: No, it's the other way around. I'd like to be able to see the FortiGate high CPU usage. Since my FortiGate FortiOS 5.4.10 does not show this information (neither from the GUI, nor from CLI), I want to get the 'FortiGate high CPU usage' information via SNMP.

Comment: But then why are you sending the queries to the CentOS SNMP server, and not to the FortiGate device?

Answer (score 2):

To poll an OID using its textual form, you should use the `MIB::OID` notation. If you're using OID in its numerical form, you can use it directly. This is because SNMP agents use numerical form and humans use textual (akin to DNS). So, agents can easily parse the numbers, but need textual forms translated into numbers. MIBs do that, so you need to specify the correct MIB where OID is defined so snmp command can translate it before polling the agent.

MIB name is defined with the `DEFINITIONS` statement in the MIB file. Don't confuse this with the name of the MIB file (sometimes the same, but not always). So, as `fgPerCpuHighDetails` in your example is defined in `FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib`, do:

`grep DEFINITIONS /home/qa/.snmp/mibs/FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.mib`

to find out the name of the MIB. I don't have this particular MIB, but likely the name will be `FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB`.

With that info you can then poll the device:

`snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.1.99 FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB::fgPerCpuHighDetails`

Use `snmptranslate` to parse the MIBs and explore them:

- `snmptranslate -Td MIB::OID` for description of an OID
- `snmptranslate -Tp MIB::OID` to map the hierarchical structure of and OID and all
  children OIDs.
- `snmptranslate -On MIB:OID` to translate an OID into numerical form
- Check man page for more options.